# Any way to use a MigLayout in GWT?

Tags: gwt, miglayout

There's a [question about using layout managers in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763250/how-much-support-does-gwt-have-for-java-layout-managers), which was however answered in the sense that no direct porting of Swing apps is possible. But I don't need this, I only want to use a sane way of positioning.

Is there a a port of MigLayout (or alike) to GWT?

<sup>Since a LayoutManager is mostly a way to set the component sizes and positions using some user preferences, it should be possible. Doing this for a HTML component is possible (and AFAIK some frameworks compute all sizes and positions on the server and avoid all associated HTML/CSS problems).</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [requested years ago](http://migcalendar.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=2343), it looks like it [hasn't been done yet](http://migcalendar.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=3339).

Just one quotation:

> I'm just getting started with GWT and I feel like I just stepped back into the dark ages with all the various layout panels and layout managers.

There's [gxt-jglayout](http://code.google.com/p/gxt-jglayout/), which is JGoodies form layout implementation for Ext-GWT (GXT), but Ext-GWT is not [free](http://www.sencha.com/store/extgwt/) (it's [dual licensed](http://www.sencha.com/products/extgwt/license/)).

Comment: GWT is not dark aged even orkut is made in GWT.

Comment: I never said, GWT was dark aged, nor did the author of the quotation. I think *GWT is very cool*, just the layouting is not as good as it could be.

Comment: They are sufficient for the use.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of crazy, the `LayoutPanel`s built in to GWT are quite sane.  There's a `DockLayoutPanel` with familiar north/south/east/west behavior, and also panels that allow more arbitrary percentages and positions.  Combining them with CSS is very powerful and flexible.

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html

Comment: I'll surely look at it. My point is that after having spent maybe half an hour with MigLayout I can do more than I could do with all the other layouts and all the time invested/wasted before. Getting CSS to work in all browsers the same is sometimes a real PITA, too. Despite the fact, that something like `[0:0, grow 25,fill]` is way beyond the imagination of W3C.